# Tensor power modulo cyclic group action

Tags: reference-request, commutative-algebra, category-theory, modules, group-actions

Let $M$ be some $R$-module and $n \geq 1$ be some positive integer. The cyclic group $\mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z}$, with a chosen generator $t$, acts on $M^{\otimes n}$ via $t(m_1 \otimes \dotsc \otimes m_n) = m_2 \otimes \dotsc \otimes m_n \otimes m_1$. We may mod out the action to obtain some $R$-module $Z_n(M) := M^{\otimes n}/(\mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z})$. Does this $R$-module have a common name? Where can I find some infos about it?

*Background.* I think that $Z(M):=\bigoplus_{n \geq 1} Z_n(M)$ might be a categorification of the power series $\sum_{n \geq 1} z^n/n = -\log(1-z)$, which is the exponential generating function of the species of cycles.

Comment: It's the $n$-th degree component $0$-th cyclic homology of the tensor algebra $T\left(M\right)$.

Comment: Ah, ok. I was already guessing that this belongs to some cyclic homology. Why not make this to an answer?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$Z_n\left(M\right)$ is the $n$-th homogeneous component of the $0$-th cyclic homology of the tensor algebra $T\left(M\right)$.

There is a nice expository note about this by Clas Löfwall, including the relation to the logarithm: [Clas Löfwall, *Cyklisk homologi*, 28 Aug 2012](http://www.researchgate.net/publication/280091408_Hochschild_homology_Lectures). Despite the title, it is in English.

Comment: Sorry for taking 8 years to accept your answer.